# In ReactiveMongo 0.18.8, how can I perform an update of several documents, with different values, in a single command?

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372398/is-there-any-way-to-perform-bulk-updates-on-reactivemongo) whilst digging in SO.

Basically, this is exactly what I need. However, it appears that in my current version of ReactiveMongo, which is 0.18.8, `db.command(RawCommand(commandDoc))` is no longer possible. There is no "command" under DB. I can't seem to find where this command moved.

Can anyone please help me? Or maybe tell me how else I can implement what I need?

I am trying to perform several updates, of several documents with different values, in a single DB command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html#update-a-document) you can see example of bulk operations to insert, update or delete.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONDocument

import reactivemongo.api.bson.collection.BSONCollection

def updateWithBulk(personColl: BSONCollection) = {
  // Bulk update: multiple update
  val updateBuilder1 = personColl.update(ordered = true)
  val updates = Future.sequence(Seq(
    updateBuilder1.element(
      q = BSONDocument("firstName" -> "Jane", "lastName" -> "Doh"),
      u = BSONDocument("age" -> 18),
      upsert = true,
      multi = false),
    updateBuilder1.element(
      q = BSONDocument("firstName" -> "Bob"),
      u = BSONDocument("age" -> 19),
      upsert = false,
      multi = true)))

  updates.flatMap { ops => updateBuilder1.many(ops) }
}
```

> Also note that version 0.18.8 is about one year old, latest version being the major release 1.0.0.